# Hide list with one element with pure CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to hide list if it contains only one element using just CSS? Bonus: think of IE8

```
<ul>
  <li>hide this</li>
<ul>
```

But:

```
<ul>
  <li>show this</li>
  <li>and others...</li>
</ul>
```

I was playing with all siblings and next selectors (`~` `+`) but there is no way to select previous CSS element :(

Comment: not clear what actually you asking?

Comment: I don't think you can count total child elements with CSS. Why not to use JS?

Comment: Where is your css code or may be you should make a fiddle?

Comment: @KheemaPandey want to hide with pure CSS HTML list element if it's only child of that list.

Comment: @HddnTHA - rlly? please...

Comment: @Justinas I don't want use JS, why to ask if it's clearly stated in my question?

Comment: @Ultra what have you tried on css part? I see only a little part of html code.

Comment: @HddnTHA it's irrelevant. I ask how YOU would do it not opposite way. Anyway you are the kind of people on SO that ask that unimportant things and don't leave any contribution what so ever. See below that others had no problems like you present.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [:has pseudo class](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/selectors-4/#relational) can be used to hide the list entirely (as apposed to just hiding the list item) when the list only has one item.

The selector can be written in a number of ways..here are two:

```
ul:not(:has(:nth-child(2))) {
  display: none
}

ul:not(:has(li + li)) {
  display: none
}
```

```css
.demo1 ul:not(:has(:nth-child(2))) {
  display: none
}

.demo2 ul:not(:has(li + li)) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="demo1">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="demo2">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Browser support for `:has` - [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

---

### Original Answer

There is a pseudo class for this:  `:only-child` (**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child)**)

So if I have the following CSS

```
li:only-child {
    display: none;
}
```

.. the list items will only be displayed if there is more than one list item.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ttpervzy/4/)**

(Note: Like Quentin said, it doesn't hide the actual list - just the list item when it is the only child... but as long as the list itself doesn't have its own styling this would be the same as hiding the list)

Also here is an excerpt from the above MDN article:

> The `:only-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element which is the
> only child of its parent. This is the same as `:first-child:last-child`
> or `:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)`, but with a lower specificity.

PS: As you can see from MDN [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child#Browser_compatibility) - IE8 doesn't support this, so for IE8 you're out of luck for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: This pseudoclass is better than @Quentin solution as its shorter. To bad cant use both in IE8

Answer (score 19):

You [can't hide the **list**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20is%20there%20a%20parent%20selector&oq=site%3Astac&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i58j69i59.2350j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8), but if the **list item** is is the *only* child, then it is both the [first](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) and [last](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo) child, so you can hide that with:

```css
li:first-child:last-child { display: none; }
```

Comment: But this does not work in IE8 http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/last-child-selector-issue-in-ie/

Comment: There is no alternative for IE8 anyway.