# Hide ul and li tag when has ul has only one li tag

Tags: html, css

Please, don't confuse this question with others published on stackoverflow.

NOTE: [Hide list with one element with pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238499/hide-list-with-one-element-with-pure-css) my question involves the parent tag.

I have these `css` rule:

```
ul {
    padding: 5px;
}

ul > li:only-child {
    display: none;
}
```

This rule hides the first `ul` tag when its only one.
But the space of the `ul` tag is still there.

How I can hide **both** `ul` and `li` when its onliy one `li` declared in my html?

Comment: Include the padding in the `li` elements instead of the `ul`

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran simple, elegant! my mistake!!! I'm not frontend developer, you have whole the right!

Comment: This would be simple if you could use javascript as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra spacing you see even after hiding the `li` elements is because you have included a `padding` for the parent `ul` element.

So the solution is to remove the padding from the `ul` element and apply it on the child `li` elements.