# Is it possible to style lists with only one item versus lists with multiple items using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

**Context**

I would like to style differently lists with only one item versus lists with multiple items.
Currently I would like to have `list-style-type:none;` and different `padding-left` for lists which have only one item.

**Question**

I do know how to write javascript code what achieves this goal by manipulating DOM, but I am asking is it possible somehow using pure CSS?

Comment: Are u able to assign different classes to the `ul` when rendering? If yes, do it and use it in your css, if not you could apply all your styling to the LIs and use the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238499/hide-list-with-one-element-with-pure-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, CSS has a built-in selector for that which is `only-child`.

You can then select child items of parents that only have one child like in the code below.

```css
p:only-child { /*this selects <p> elements of parents that have only one <p> child */
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>I am an only child</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>We are many childs</p>
  <p>We are many childs</p>
  <p>We are many childs</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer, code only answer are in general not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using "only-child" CSS pseudo-class, like below.

```css
li{ color:red}
li:only-child {
color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1st Item</li>
  <li>2nd Item</li>
  <li>3rd Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Only Item</li>
</ul>
```

Here when ul has only child element its color will be green. And when
ul has multiple child element's there color will be red. You can find more details about it on [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child).

Answer (score 1):

There's a really nice pseudo-class, only-child, in CSS but some older browsers don't support it so if you need to support older versions you can use both first and last child selectors on an element:

```css
li:first-child:last-child {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>List with only one entry</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Only child</li>
</ul>
<h2>List with more than one entry</h2>
<ul>
  <li>first li</li>
  <li>second li</li>
</ul>
```